# How to check if screen is inhibited D-Bus in Rust with zbus

Tags: rust, dbus

I want to call the `HasInhibit` method at `org.freedesktop.PowerManagement. [I can call it from within QDBusViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z17CQ.png). I'm using the zbus crate.

Here is why I tried, but it just errors out every time:

```rust
let connection = Connection::session().await?;

let reply = connection
    .call_method(
        Some("org.freedesktop.PowerManagement"),
        "/org/freedesktop/PowerManagement",
        Some("org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit"),
        "HasInhibit",
        &(),
    )
    .await?;
println!("Reply: {:?}", reply.body()?);
```

Error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to check for inhibit: Variant(SignatureMismatch(Signature("b"), "``"))', src/main.rs:71:18
```